How can I make a low poly shape like this with triangular faces
How can I make on a rounded shape like random triangles appearing on its surface like the reference image, or if its not possible on a rounded shape, then to make these triangular looking shapes.



Add a sphere.
Shape it in sculpt mode.
Add a displacement modifier with noise.
Add a decimate modifier and reduce the ratio.



Wow, thanks for that, I didnt even know where to begin from!
